# Confusing source code in TrollTech's Qt Tutorial Ch11

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am learning Qt from TrollTech's Qt Tutorial these days, and I'am confused about the source code of calculating the position of bullet in [this page](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.2/tutorial-t11.html):

```
QRect CannonField::shotRect() const
{
    const double gravity = 4;

    double time = timerCount / 20.0;
    double velocity = shootForce;
    double radians = shootAngle * 3.14159265 / 180;

    double velx = velocity * cos(radians);
    double vely = velocity * sin(radians);
    double x0 = (barrelRect.right() + 5) * cos(radians);
    double y0 = (barrelRect.right() + 5) * sin(radians);
    double x = x0 + velx * time;
    double y = y0 + vely * time - 0.5 * gravity * time * time;

    QRect result(0, 0, 6, 6);
    result.moveCenter(QPoint(qRound(x), height() - 1 - qRound(y)));
    return result;
}
```

In the third-last line:

```
result.moveCenter(QPoint(qRound(x), height() - 1 - qRound(y)));
```

I think that `- 1` is nonsense, isn't it?

Comment: It appears to be taking a scalar count (from height) and adjusting it to a 0-based array; so a height of 1 would correspond to the 0 index of the array. Just a guess.

Comment: Agree with tbert:  Without knowing the semantics of `height()`'s return value, subtracting `1` may or may not be significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a widget:

[image: Widget]

If the height of widget is `height`, then `y == 0` line is on the top of the widget and bottom line has `y == height - 1` coordinate. So, if you want to show a point on the bottom line of the widget, you should set it `y` coordinate to `height - 1`.

Apparently, they use bottom of the widget as a ground level, so the bullet can be only above or on this level.

Comment: I finally figured it out! Thanks a million, Lol4t0!